# I'm new to this, What am I doing wrong? Creating array of line items in JSON and getting parse error. - Expecting 'STRING', got '{'

Tags: arrays, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajRg.png)

```
Parse error on line 15:
...,
        "Qty": 3
}, 
{
        "Amount":
--------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '{'
```

I don't know how to format the code for stack overflow but this is the JSON array I'm trying to put together

```
{
  "MetaData": {
    "CreateTime": "2019-05-16T18:13:13-08:00",
    "LastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-16T18:13:45-08:00"
  },
  "Line": [{
        "Amount": 135,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
        "ItemRef": {
        "value": "1",
        "name": "LV"
        },
        "Qty": 3
}, 
{
        "Amount": 135,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
        "ItemRef": {
        "value": "1",
        "name": "LV"
        },
        "Qty": 3
}    }
  ],
  "CustomerRef": {
    "value": "20"
  }
}
```

The solution is probably simple

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing bracket anywhere. A formatted version of that data could help you

Comment: "Creating array of line items" - how **exactly** do you do that?

Comment: [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)  will help you

Comment: Your JSON as posted is malformed.

Comment: @NicoHaase am using a web-site builder called bubble, I can insert dynamic data from bubble's database by formatting the stored data as JSON. My goal is to create an invoice in quickbooks online by sending the formatted JSON through an api.

Comment: @Gereon How malformed is it? where can I learn how to form it?

Comment: The number of open and closing braces does not match. See https://json.org for the format definition. If you get this JSON from some database or API, contact the vendor as this seems to be a bug on their part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "MetaData": {
    "CreateTime": "2019-05-16T18:13:13-08:00",
    "LastUpdatedTime": "2019-05-16T18:13:45-08:00"
  },
  "Line": [
    {
        "Amount": 135,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
            "ItemRef": {
                "value": "1",
                "name": "LV"
             },
            "Qty": 3
        }                                    <--- MISSING BRACE HERE
    }, 
    {
        "Amount": 135,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
            "ItemRef": {
                "value": "1",
                "name": "LV"
            },
            "Qty": 3
        }
    }
  ],
  "CustomerRef": {
    "value": "20"
  }
}
```